# What is the latex code for flow chart?

Tags: flow-charts

What is latex code for the following figure.[image]

Comment: Please don't just let the people here do the work for you. Search for flow chart on this site and you will find plenty examples. Start with your own example and refine your question with what you got and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3):

in my examples' barn i found the following flowchart:

[image]

it can serve you for starting point. if in adopting it to your needs will stuck, ask for help ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\tikzset{FlowChart/.style={
startstop/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=red!30,
                    minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
                    on chain, join=by arrow},
  process/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, fill=blue!30,
                    text width=5cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center,
                    on chain, join=by arrow},
 decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.3, draw, fill=green!30,
                    minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center,
                    on chain, join=by arrow},
    arrow/.style = {thick,-Triangle}
        }   }

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
    node distance = 5mm and 7mm,
      start chain = A going below
                        ]
% nodes in chain                        
\node [startstop] {Inicio};                 % node name: A-1
\node [process]   {Propiedades de la garganta a partir de cámara de combustión:\\
                     $P_0,T_0,\rho_0 \to P_t, T_t, \rho_t$};        % A-2
\node [process]   {Presión de salida:\\
                   $P_s \to T_s, \rho_s, M_s, v_s, \varepsilon$};   % A-3
\node [process]   {Escoger dimensiones garganta y calcular mass flow:\\
                    $D_t \circ A_t \to \dot{m}, A_s, F$};           % A-4
\node [decision]  {$F\geq \SI{500}{N}?$};   % A-5
\node [decision]  {$P_s \leq P_s (\min)$};  % A-6
\node [startstop] {Fin};                    % A-7
% labels of some join lines
\node[below right] at (A-5.south) {Si};                                                               \node[below right] at (A-6.south) {Si};     
% lines not drawn by join
    \draw [arrow] (A-5.east) node[above right] {No} -- + (2.5,0) |- (A-4);
    \draw [arrow] (A-6.east) node[above right] {No} -- + (3.0,0) |- (A-3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: sir I would like to know how we add the comment step 1 identification an step 2 Estimation etc as in pic to our flow chart

Comment: @seena, i give you only frame how to draw flow chart. at least you can replace existed text with yours, delete nodes which you not use (for example first one and  "decision" node) and show us (in your question), what you obtain and what you like to change further.